# retrieve data from multiple tables which is having the same id

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a problem with sql query. Actually, I want to intersection of two tables. Here are my tables.

```
Les_Teach
+--------+-----------+
| les_id | teach_id  |
+--------+-----------+
|   10    |     1     |
|   10    |     2     |
|   10    |     3     |
|   11    |     1     |
|   11    |     6     |
+--------+-----------+

Class_Les
+--------+-----------+
| c_id   | les_id    |
+--------+-----------+
|   10    |     1     |
|   10    |     3     |
|   11    |     5     |
|   11    |     1     |
|   11    |     6     |
|   11    |     7     |
+--------+-----------+
```

Example 1) Intersection for les_id and c_id is 10;

```
Query Result 1
+--------+-----------+
|   10    |     1     |
|   10    |     3     |
+--------+-----------+
```

Example 2) Intersection for les_id and c_id is 11;

```
Query Result 2
+--------+-----------+
|   11    |     1     |
|   11    |     6     |
+--------+-----------+
```

SELECT DISTINCT
cl.les_id
FROM
Class_Les cl
INNER JOIN Les_Teach lt
ON lt.les_id=cl.c_id
WHERE lt.les_id=10 AND cl.c_id=10

Only for les_id column in Les_Teach and c_id column in Class_Les, how can I retrieve data like this?

Comment: What is the logic for "intersection"?  You examples don't clarify what you want to do.

Comment: This is an inner join on two columns. Do you want a filtered result, or the full intersection?

Comment: I tried inner join but didn't do it. No, I don't want full intersection.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski did you join on the correct columns? (les_id with c_id, teach_id with les_id) That is what would get you your desired output (although the column names don't match)

Comment: Please post the queries you are using.

Comment: Are the two result sets you posted the results that you WANT, or what you are getting (and don't want)?

Comment: No, results are just an example for 10 and 11

Comment: So they are or are not examples of what you want (for 10/11)? If they are not what you want, please provide the desired output.

Comment: I want to output like above examples for only one value.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "only one value". If the output above is exactly like what you want, you can use my answer. Otherwise modify your question to include the result that you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the examples you gave are of the results you want to get, you can use -

for 10:

```
select x.*
  from les_teach x
  join class_les y
    on x.les_id = y.c_id
   and x.teach_id = y.les_id
where x.les_id = 10;
```

for 11:

```
select x.*
  from les_teach x
  join class_les y
    on x.les_id = y.c_id
   and x.teach_id = y.les_id
 where x.les_id = 11;
```

(leave out the where clause for the full intersection of the two tables)

Test -

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a25e87/3